# How to parse RDF using .NET

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, rdf

Is there a way to parse RDF using .NET? I would like to show the data in some web control?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, there is a way. Look for an RDF library for .NET and use it. In the future, when asking a question, please explain what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: Related Questions - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/240903/what-is-a-good-rdf-library-for-net and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4356839/how-do-i-get-started-with-sparql-as-a-net-developer

Comment: Also duplicated at http://answers.semanticweb.com/questions/14352/how-to-show-data-from-rdf-in-web-controls

Comment: I agree with @Oded - this is far too vague as a question and a simple Google search would have given you too good APIs - including my own ;-) - in the top three search results and a link to a SO question covering RDF libraries for .Net

Comment: Check http://codecanyon.net/item/feed-reader-for-rssatom-and-rdf-using-aspnet/16181586 . Very easy integration and supports multiple Feeds like RSS,RDF and ATOM. It is a paid solution but a worth try.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is. For instance with:

- [ROWLEX](http://rowlex.nc3a.nato.int/HowToUse.aspx)
- [SemWeb.NET](http://razor.occams.info/code/semweb/)
- [dotNetRDF](http://www.dotnetrdf.org/)

In dotNetRdf several classes (for example [IGraph.ToDataTable()](http://www.dotnetrdf.org/api/dotNetRDF~VDS.RDF.IGraph.ToDataTable.html)) offer methods which will convert the RDF triples to a `DataTable`.